# STMicro library for setting RTC Alarm on Sunday is incorrect?

Tags: rtc

I'm using a stm32fxx ARM Cortex-M3. When setting an RTC alarm for Sunday, I realized that the stm32l1xx_rtc.h header file defined Sunday as:

```
#define RTC_Weekday_Sunday             ((uint8_t)0x07)
```

In code, I do this:

```
rtc_alarm.RTC_AlarmDateWeekDay      = RTC_Weekday_Sunday;
```

But no alarm is fired when I used this value. Instead, I tried inputting 0x0 whenever I want to set an alarm on Sunday, then that seems to work just fine! So here is my hypothesis:

1. I have used the wrong header file for the F series
2. I have to do a mod 7 operation when setting weekday? I found nothing on a spec that mentioned this.
3. STMicro header file has a bug

If someone with knowledge can help me understand this problem?

Comment: Is this... software? Would this be better suited to the STM forum or some kind of software/stack exchange?

Comment: @KryanF eh, this is a firmware question. But I put the question in all forums though so if this is not the right place it will be abandoned soon.

Comment: Ah, i guess firmware is more accurate, yes, sorry. The concept of this electronics stack exchange is more for electronics design rather than the use of them once they are 'designed' haha. Firmware mostly falls under that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a common situation where the Day-Of-Week is represented as a value of 1 -> 7. You can also find situations where the DOW is represented by numbers 0 -> 6.

I have also seen situations where sometimes Sunday is considered the first day of the week with the lowest DOW number and others where Sunday is considered the last day of the week with the highest numbered DOW number.

You have to do whatever it takes to adapt your application environment to the DOW number system used in your RTC chip. If that takes a little software coding on your part then that just becomes a part of the job.

So I would recommend that it is better to track toward what works instead of trying to figure out what may or may not be wrong with chipset library code.

Comment: In this case, I have seen that DOW is represented 0->6 with Sunday being the lowest DOW number, contrary to what ST has claimed in their library. I can simply define the DOW number to work with the chipset and not using the library code, just wasn't sure if I would create other problems by bypassing their supplied library. I contacted ST directly for this question so I'll put an answer here if I got a reply.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this mystery by realizing that when setting the RTC_Date, while I have supplied the DayOfMonth value, I also need to supply the DayOfWeek value to the register also instead of leaving it blank. I was under the impression that the RTC module can compute the DayOfWeek from a given date (with Year/Month/DayOfMonth), but that wasn't the case.